# JBoss without multicast?

Tags: jboss, multicast

Does anyone know if it is possible to run JBoss as a cluster using only unicast, no multicast?

More importantly, does anyone have experience actually getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The unicast should be doable using a `GossipRouter` (as referenced in the [JGroups Manual](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html) - see sections 5.3.1 and 5.3.2).

In our cluster, we use TCP multicast for the production instance. However, our unit tests for our JBoss Cache listeners require a pseudo-clustered environment, and we use a `GossipRouter` instance to successfully create a transient cluster that lives for the life of the unit tests and allows successful cluster communication.